# Connect to mysqli with a string?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a function that return a string (with the database credentials), this string called `$conn_db` is like this:

```
host= localhost ;username= root ;password= 123456 ;database= test ;
```

now in my function for establish a database connection if I pass the value like so:

```
mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname)
```

all working good but. If I pass the connection string only:

```
mysqli_connect($conn_db)
```

an exception is returned in the:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{ 
     throw new Exception("Can't establish db connection");
}
```

isn't possible use a connection string instead of 4 variables in `mysqli_connect`?

Comment: `host= localhost ;username= root ;password= 123456 ;database= test ;` you are using `$` for those, *right?*. Otherwise, you'd be getting undefined constants notices. and just doing `mysqli_connect($conn_db)` won't work here. Unsure what you're trying to do here though; avoid additional parameters?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, how you can see I just want pass a connection string instead of all parameters. The connection string how you can see in the example contain all the information for establish the connection.

Comment: the question is: *why?*

Comment: the answer is: why not?

Comment: hehehe, ok. Well, you could probably set it up as an array. I'm thinking outloud here, of course ;-) see Marc's answer then. Ask him now.

Comment: well actually I have already an array with connection parameter... but I just want to know if is possible use a single connection string, but I think that's not possible.

Comment: with a bit of tinkering, I could probably pull something off, but TBH, I don't have time to tinker right now ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. `mysqli_connect()` expects multiple arguments. When you do `mysqli_connect($db_conn)`, you're passing **ONE** argument. The mysqli library, and underlying mysql driver, are NOT going to parse that string to try and extract whatever other parameters are necessary. You can't embed multiple values in a single argument either, and expect that to make sense.

Since you only provide `$db_conn`, that's what MySQL will try to use as the hostname (argument #1), and try to do a DNS lookup on some nonsensical "username=foo&password=bar"-type hostname, which will obviously fail.

If you want to use a single string/argument, then switch to PDO. Its constructor allows for such things.

Comment: Uhm, I'm sad for this. In other languages is possible pass a formatted connection string as c# for example. But okay, thanks for clarify this.

Comment: this has nothing to do with php. this is how the mysqli interface was designed. and frankly, multiple arguments that explicitly state what they're for is far better than some massive long string that requires a full-blown parser to evaluate.

Comment: I guess you're right for multiple value instead of one string. Thanks anyway :)